# How to add Multiple Column in table in alter command

Tags: db2, db2-luw

i want to add multiple column in existng table with the help of alter query.

```
ALTER TABLE users.UM_REG_HPTL_DET_DOC  
  ADD column HPTL_TADDRESS3 vargraphic(50),
  ADD column APPLICANT_ADDRESS3 varchar(50),
  ADD column APPLICANT_TADDRESS3(50),
  ADD column aadhar_no varchar(12),
  ADD column Registration_no varchar(50);
```

than that  error comes

An unexpected token "," was found following "RESS3 vargraphic(50)".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove ","  and than run

```
ALTER TABLE users.UM_REG_HPTL_DET_DOC
  ADD column HPTL_TADDRESS3 vargraphic(50)
  ADD column APPLICANT_ADDRESS3 varchar(50)
  ADD column APPLICANT_TADDRESS3(50)
  ADD column aadhar_no varchar(12)
  ADD column Registration_no varchar(50);
```